# Compress/Shrink/Optimize groovy-all, groovy 2.0.1 for distribution?

Tags: java, groovy, proguard

I'm trying to shrink the size of the groovy libraries (which are required for my groovy/java application to run properly) as they are around 6.2 MB, this is quite large compared to the complexity of my application. As such, i wish to Shrink and if possible optimise the groovy 2.0.1 libraries for my application.

I've already tried running the groovy-all and groovy-2.0.1 jars through pro-guard  but i get heaps warnings and errors. I've searched Google to see if anyone has successfully done this before but i still can't find anything useful.

Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using pack200 and unpack200?

Comment: Never heard of those, will investigate and report back... thanks

Comment: @PeterLawrey They look good but unfortunately run-time decompression isn't what i'm looking for...

Comment: You could compressing and decompressing at build time.  These tools give you options to remove bits which are not required like debug information.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Not sure what you mean at build time.. All i'm saying is the groovy library is fairly huge for a small utility application (~250 KB) (~6.2MB)

Comment: If you use pack200 and then unpack200 you have the option of removing any bits you don't really need.  Personally I wouldn't worry about 6 MB as the information you remove you might find you need later e.g. debug information. 6 MB of disk space is less than a cent.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That doesn't really solve the question.I will look into it, however.

Comment: It will make the jar smaller.  You wouldn't want to extract just the bit you think you need because that is very unreliable and difficult to maintain.  Given the disk space used is trivial and the memory used will be small, I wouldn't spend much time on it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Alright, after further looking into Pack200, Unpack200 it does look like it's the way to go.. I'm guessing i should unpack at first run-time (store in temp folder)? or just unpack every run?

Comment: I would test it and see if unpacking it each time is fast enough.  Perhaps you can check to see if there is an unpacked temporary file which is newer before unpacking again. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey but.. after it's unpacked how would i load the unpacked jar?

Comment: The unpacked jar would need to be in your classpath. It can be in your classpath before it exists if that helps.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Okay, so i tried this: http://pastie.org/private/usx6awqcla1ijau9bzr8nq (with a scala app i made) but i get: http://pastie.org/4661251 Even though when i unpack200 in CLI it works "unpack200 scalalib.pack.tgz out.jar" < works. But in code, no?

Comment: I thought pack200 just created a pack file which you unpack.  I wouldn't expect to see `.gz` or `JarOutputStream` as these are different compression tools.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Unpack200 unpacks pack200 files AFAIK. I only packed using default settings, so i don't see why this shouldn't work?

Comment: I would take gz and Jars out of the code.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What do you mean?

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to use GZIP or JarOutputStream to use Pack or Unpack classes. You may be able to use these as well but it could be confusing things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16272/discussion-between-daniel-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about groovy modularity? Can't you remove some jars? Or you need everything it offers?

Take a look at http://www.infoq.com/articles/new-groovy-20

**Groovy modules**

So the first goal of the modularity aspect of this release is to actually split the original Groovy JAR into smaller modules, smaller JARs. The core Groovy JAR is now twice as small, and we have the following feature modules available:

Modules:

```
Ant: for scripting Ant tasks for automating administration tasks
BSF: for integrating Groovy in your Java applications with the old Apache Bean Scripting Framework
Console: module containing the Groovy Swing console
GroovyDoc: for documenting your Groovy and Java classes
Groovysh: module corresponding to the Groovysh command-line shell
JMX: for exposing and consuming JMX beans
JSON: for producing and consuming JSON payloads
JSR-223: for integrating Groovy in your Java applications with the JDK 6+ javax.scripting APIs
Servlet: for writing and serving Groovy script servlets and templates
SQL: for querying relational databases
Swing: for building Swing UIs
Templates: for using the template engine
Test: for some test support, like the GroovyTestCase, mocking, and more
TestNG: for writing TestNG tests in Groovy
XML: for producing and consuming XML documents
```

Comment: so what is the base module for basic groovy?

Comment: it's the `groovy-2.0.1.jar`, whose size is half the original jar size